# $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(\ln 4)^{k}}{k!} $

Tags: calculus, summation, logarithms, infinity

I'm taking single variable calculus on Coursera platform and asked :

> Calculate $$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{(\ln 4)^{k}}{k!} $$

The natural logarithm of a number is its logarithm to base $e$ but how can this be calculated with above formula ?

Update :

substituting $x=-a$ , $a=\ln4$ in $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}=e^x$

gives :

> $$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k}\frac{(\ln 4)^{k}}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-\ln 4)^{k}}{k!} =e^{-\ln4}=\frac14 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}=e^x
$$

> What if $x=-a$?

> And what if $a=\ln4$?

Comment: please see question update

Comment: @blue-sky You can do it in a single passage: set $x=-\ln4$, so the sum is $e^{-\ln4}=\dots$